# CSS - Text to the right of custom checkbox

Tags: html, css

I have a custom checkbox that edits the `label` tag to create the look and feel. With the `label` tag used, I'm not sure how to have the checkbox text appear to the right of the box.

```css
input#check {
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
}
input#check:checked + label svg path {
  stroke-dashoffset: 0;
}


#check + label {
  display: block;
  border: 4px solid #333;
  width: var(--d);
  height: var(--d);
  border-radius: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all 0.2s ease;
}

#check + label svg {
  pointer-events: none;
}
#check + label svg path {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #333;
  stroke-width: 6px;
  stroke-linecap: round;
  stroke-linejoin: round;
  stroke-dasharray: 100;
  stroke-dashoffset: 101;

}

.checkbox-label {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: 70px;
}
```

```html
<div class="form">
  <input type="checkbox" id="check"/>
  <label for="check" style="--d: 40px">
    <svg viewBox="0,0,50,50">
      <path d="M10 35 L 20 45 L 40 10"></path>
    </svg>
  </label>
</div>

<div class=checkbox-label>
<p> Label here </p>
</div>
```

I've tried using `in-line block` and `span` within the `label` tag but the text appears either below the box or within in. How can I have it appear to the right? To show the location, I added in some text with an absolute location, but would like to do this without using absolute position as I can't repeat this when I add in new checkboxes.

Comment: Do you want checkbox and then label on the right without using position absolute?

Comment: I want the checkbox, on the left and the label to the right of the checkbox

Comment: That's exactly what I see when I run your snippet. A checkbox on the left and the text on the right. On Chrome, Edge and Firefox. Please edit your question and clarify.

Comment: Your question is not clear, Please give the proper explanation with a screenshot. If possible.

Comment: I edited the question. I showed the text where I want it using an absolute position, but I am looking how to do this without using absolute position, which is difficult to duplicate

Comment: Use flexbox to achieve your goal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use a wrapper and apply flexbox rules.

```css
.wrapper{ 
  display:flex; 
  gap:2rem;/* control the gap between elements */
}
input#check {
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
}

input#check:checked+label svg path {
  stroke-dashoffset: 0;
}

#check+label {
  display: block;
  border: 4px solid #333;
  width: var(--d);
  height: var(--d);
  border-radius: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all 0.2s ease;
}

#check+label svg {
  pointer-events: none;
}

#check+label svg path {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #333;
  stroke-width: 6px;
  stroke-linecap: round;
  stroke-linejoin: round;
  stroke-dasharray: 100;
  stroke-dashoffset: 101;
}

.checkbox-label {
  /*position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: 70px;*/
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">  
  <div class="form">
    <input type="checkbox" id="check" />
    <label for="check" style="--d: 40px">
      <svg viewBox="0,0,50,50">
        <path d="M10 35 L 20 45 L 40 10"></path>
      </svg>
    </label>
  </div>

  <div class=checkbox-label>
    <p> Label here </p>
  </div>
</div>
```